# Findind a $C^1$ path $\gamma: (-1, 1) \rightarrow S^{n-1}$ so that: $\gamma (0)=x, \gamma '(0) =v$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a unit vector ($|x|=1$). Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ so that $\left \langle v, x \right \rangle =0$. Prove that there is a $C^1$ path $\gamma: (-1, 1) \rightarrow S^{n-1}$ (unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$) so that:
$\gamma (0)=x, \gamma '(0) =v$.

I know that the opposite is true: in such $\gamma$, it must hold that $\left \langle \gamma (0), \gamma '(0) \right \rangle =0$. But how can I show the other direction?

Ideas will be welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about
$$
\gamma(t)=\frac{x+t\,v}{\|x+t\,v\|}=\frac{x+t\,v}{\sqrt{1+t^2\,\|v\|^2}}\ ?
$$

Comment: Oh, you're right. I guess I haven't thought about it enough.thank you